# Is there a way to delete objects without confirmation?

Tags: interface

I'm a beginner in Blender. I started using it and found that in order to delete something I gotta confirm the action.

Can it be disabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Blender 2.8 onwards you can delete without confirmation by pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Though deleting with <kbd>X</kbd> by default asks for a confirmation, you can opt out of this by changing the keymap for *Object Mode> Delete* as commented by @sambler.

[image: Unchecked confirm option]

Comment: While 2.7x always needs to confirm deleting, in 2.80 confirm to delete objects is an option and we can disable it and save it in our [keymap settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwPO4.jpg).